# Manage Rails model classes across repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, elasticsearch, tire

My project has the following setup. I have two repositories (seprate projects):

1. one that generates my model classes (Ruby)
2. one that works with my model classes (Rails)

The first one writes the model objects to my database (ElasticSearch) and the second one reads them again. Now I am using the persistence layer of ElasticSearch and basically I have **redundant** class definitions in both projects.

I would like to resolve this redundancy, but how does one normally approach this? I don't want to merge both projects. Should I use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this?

How do I deal with different namespaces?

Comment: why do you exactly have 2 different repositories? Is that really necessary?

Comment: @Mattherick No, that's not really necessary, no one forces me to do that, but I like it to offer two stand-alone projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution based on git then either submodules or subtree. Both have different use-case scenarios, which is worth studying.